# How to extract text from a-html elements by using a customized function?

Tags: python, html, function, web-scraping

I am trying to extract `a` text sub-elements for the first `table` element from an specific url.

The main goal is to iterate over all `a` sub-elements in order to extract `#text`  as a list.
To accomplish this task I defined a function:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import requests

url = 'https://www.salario.com.br/profissao/abacaxicultor-cbo-612510/'

def getColumns(url):
    url = requests.get(url)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(url.text, 'lxml')
    table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'listas'})

     # getting salary table (first table on job_title.url)
      # finding table headers

    #first_header = table.find('thead').find('tr').find_all('strong')
    all_other_headers = table.find('thead').find('tr').find('a').find_all('data-tooltip')
    colnames = [hdr.text for hdr in all_other_headers]
   

    return colnames
```

When applied `getColumns(url)` it returns an empty list :`[]`, when I expect an output that looks like this: `['Sálario Mensal', 'Sálario Anual', 'Salário por Semana', 'Sálario por Hora']`

Why if I am using `a` tag is still not working?
How could I possibly adjust this function?

Comment: Are you sure the "td" in `.find('td')` is the correct element? From what I can see on the website the child you're looking for seems to be "tr".

Comment: Thanks for the observation, just updated the function, gettin' the same output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks like this is perhaps being made more complicated than necessary. In general, I find it easiest to think of parsing with BeautifulSoup as a progression of searching further and further down the document tree.

So for this example I'd think in terms of these steps

1. find the `table` element
2. get the `thead` element
3. find all `td` elements in the `thead`
4. find all the `a` elements and their string value

Here's an example of that approach which gives the output that you're looking for.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import requests

def getColumns(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    table = soup.find('table')
    thead = table.find('thead')
    headers = thead.find_all('td')
    headerNames = [td.find('a').string for td in headers if td.find('a')]

    return headerNames

headerNames = getColumns('https://www.salario.com.br/profissao/abacaxicultor-cbo-612510/')
print(headerNames)
```